# Close Socket from outside socket thread

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I am using an automation program for Mac called Indigo. In the plugin I am working a socket is opened when the the plugin starts by calling `openSocket(self)`. Once the socket is open, Indigo method `runConcurrentThread(self)` runs in a separate thread to receive any data from the client.

My problem is when the plugin is called to shutdown or reload, the thread created by `runConcurrentThread(self)` is supposed to stop but it times out and is force closed. The socket must be closed first so it doesn't block the thread closing but I can't figure how to do it.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
# http://wiki.indigodomo.com/doku.php?id=indigo_6_documentation:plugin_guide
# called by startup(self) on starting the plugin
def openSocket(self):

    self.debugLog('openSocket method called')

    for dev in indigo.devices.iter("self"):
        props = dev.pluginProps

    self.PORT = int(dev.pluginProps['rpiSockPort'])  # Arbitrary non-privileged port 8888 is a good one

    if dev.pluginProps['rpiHost'] == "all":
        HOST = ''
    else:
        HOST = dev.pluginProps['rpiHost'] 

    self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    self.debugLog('Socket created')

    try:
        self.s.bind((HOST, self.PORT))
    except socket.error , msg:
        self.debugLog('Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
        sys.exit()

    self.debugLog('Socket bind complete')

    self.s.listen(5)

    self.debugLog('Socket now listening')       


#called by Indigo after startup(self)
def runConcurrentThread(self):

    try:

        while True:
            self.errorLog("runConcurrentThread starting")

            #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
            conn, addr = self.s.accept()
            connIp = addr[0]
            connPort = str(addr[1])

            data = conn.recv(1024)

            reply = 'the server received ' + data + '\n'

            if not data: 
                sys.exit()

            conn.sendall(reply)

            # method to update the data in Indigo
            self.updateDeviceStates(self.PORT, connIp, connPort, data)


    except self.StopThread:
        self.debugLog("rpi main thread stopping")
```

Comment: Can't you just make it do a non-blocking `self.s.accept()` in a loop and occationally check if the thread should stop?

Comment: make the thread daemon. The program will exit without waiting for such thread to finish